# Turning a JavaScript array into a group of buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have an input bar that allows you to search for item (products), but I want it to become a list of buttons. Also, when you click it, it should add the item to a shopping cart.

```js
var storeProductArray = [{
    ItemId: '000000001',
    ItemDes: 'Milk',
    ItemCost: 10,
    ItemGSTAmt: 1,
    ItemApplyDisc: true
  },
  {
    ItemId: '000000002',
    ItemDes: 'Yogurt',
    ItemCost: 15,
    ItemGSTAmt: 1.5,
    ItemApplyDisc: true
  },
  {
    ItemId: '000000003',
    ItemDes: 'Vegetable',
    ItemCost: 15,
    ItemGSTAmt: 1.5,
    ItemApplyDisc: true
  },
  {

    ItemId: '000000004',
    ItemDes: 'Fruit',
    ItemCost: 20,
    ItemGSTAmt: 2,
    ItemApplyDisc: true
  },
  {

    ItemId: '000000005',
    ItemDes: 'Chicken',
    ItemCost: 13,
    ItemGSTAmt: 1.3,
    ItemApplyDisc: true
  }
]
```

```html
<div ng-show="login">
  <input type="text" ng-trim="false" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item as item.ItemId for item in storeProductArray | filter:{ItemId:$viewValue}" maxlength="9" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Product" />
  <div ng-show="selected.ItemId !== undefined">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item Code</td>
          <td>{{selected.ItemId}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item Description</td>
          <td>{{selected.ItemDes}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item Price</td>
          <td>{{selected.ItemCost}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item MultiSelect</td>
          <td><input type="CheckBox" ng-model="selected.ItemApplyDisc"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="purchaseItem()">Purchase Item</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="purchasedProductArray.length > 0">
    <div id="receipt">
      <h2 class="header"> Your purchased products </h2>
      <table class="table">
        <tbody ng-repeat="product in purchasedProductArray">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="6">{{product.productId}}</td>
            <td rowspan="6">{{product.productDes}}</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>{{product.productCost}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total Price Without Discount and Tax</td>
            <td>{{product.totPriceWithoutTax_Discount}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DisAmount</td>
            <td>{{product.disPrice}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>GSTAmount</td>
            <td>{{product.productGSTAmt}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>TotalPrice</td>
            <td>{{product.totPrice}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td>Total Amount</td>
          <td>${{totalAmt}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="print();">Print Receipt</button>
```

This is part of my code and I am not sure how to make it so that there is a list of buttons with individual items name. When you click it, it should add it to shopping cart.

Is this possible?

Any help is accepted, and thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using Angular, please tag it accordingly for better response

Comment: I see that you miss `]`  and redundant `HTML` at the end of `var storeProductArray = [`

Comment: The above closing bracket was indeed missing. There was also an additional `</td>` in the code. I've fixed both of these issues in my formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inside an `ng-repeat`, you need to pass in the item that needs to be processed.

```
<td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="purchaseItem(product)">Purchase Item</button></td>
```

Then inside your controller handle accordingly

```
$scope.purchaseItem = function(product) {
  alert("I'm buying "+ product.ItemDes);
}
```